# Postgres jsonb index on nested integer field

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb

I've got the following data structure in my postgres database - a jsonb column called `customer`

```
{
    "RequestId": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
    "Customer": {
        "Status": "A",
        "AccountId": 14603582,
        "ProfileId": 172,
        "ReferralTypeId": 15
    }
    "Contact": {
        "Telephone": "",
        "Email": ""
    }   
}
```

I want to create an index on the `ProfileId` field, which is an integer.

I've been unable to find an example of how to create an index on a nested field.

The query I'm executing (which takes ~300s) is:

```
select id, customer from where customer @> '{"Customer":{"ProfileId": 172}}'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator classes `jsonb_path_ops` and `jsonb_ops` for GIN indexes [support the `@>` operator](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gin-builtin-opclasses.html#GIN-BUILTIN-OPCLASSES-TABLE).

So your query should be able to use the following index

```
create index on the_table using gin (customer);
```

which uses the default `jsonb_ops` operator.

According to the manual the `jsonb_path_ops` operator is faster but only supports the `@>` operator. So if that is the only type of condition you have (for that column), using `jsonb_path_ops` might be more efficient:

```
create index on the_table using gin (customer jsonb_path_ops);
```

Comment: as I only want to index by one or two fields, is it possible to isolate the index to particular field??  
e.g. 

`CREATE INDEX on the_table USING GIN ((customer -> 'Customer' -> 'ProfileId') jsonb_path_ops);`

Comment: For that expression you don't need a GIN index. A btree index will be much more efficient. The GIN index is intended for situations where you don't know which keys (or paths) in the JSON your condition will contain

Comment: Something like this would work no? `CREATE INDEX idx_content_metadata_pn_qwire_id ON your_table((customer->>'Customer'->> 'ProfileId'));`