# Indexing JSONField in Django PostgreSQL

Tags: django, postgresql

I am using a simple model with an attribute that stores all the data for that object in a JSONField. Think of it as way to transfer NoSQL data to my PostgreSQL database. Kinda like this:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField   

class Document(models.Model):
    content = JSONField()
```

Each `Document` object has (more or less) the same keys in its `content` field, so I am querying and ordering those documents using those keys. For the querying and ordering, I am using Django's `annotate()` function. I recently came across this:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/

I also know that PostgreSQL using JSONB, which is apparently indexible. So my question is this: Can I index my `content` field somehow to make my read operations faster for complex queries? And if so, then how do I do it? The documentation page I linked has no examples.

Comment: I think there are similar questions related to this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/49358119/4116955 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17807030/how-to-create-index-on-json-field-in-postgres-9-3  Please migrate your json data to a postgresql table using its JSONB type and then try indexing the whole column or a specific field in the json payload.

Comment: Thats interesting. However, I was looking for a way to do this from within Django, as that would make my codebase much more easier to manage.

Comment: Something like this should work - `class Doc(models.Model):
    data = JSONField()

    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(
                fields=['data'],
                name='data_gin',
            ),
        ]`   Sorry for the bad formatting.

Comment: Wouldn't this index the entire column? Is that a good idea considering there might be all sorts of data types within that JSONField?

Comment: I think this index will work when you query for rows in a table where the key in a JSONB field maps to a particular value

Comment: And also for the best performance, you have to rely on postgresql indices, because it is more a powerful way than index definitions in your python code. For DB performance, you must tune the DB itself rather than your code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Django 3.2 introduced native support for these indexes, as [Tim Tisdall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/918558/tim-tisdall) commented in another answer. If you are adding these to an existing model, be sure to [`makemigrations` and `migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#the-commands).

---

To index a particular key, you combine an [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) with a [JSONField path lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#key-index-and-path-transforms) on [the model's Meta `indexes` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#indexes):

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField   

class Document(models.Model):
    content = JSONField()
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(models.F("content__example_field_name"), name="content__example_field_name_idx"),
        ]
```

[This will create a B-Tree index.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/indexes/#index-options)

---

If you want to use [filters, like `has_key` on a top-level field,](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#has-key) (e.g. `Document.objects.filter(content__has_key="example_field_name")`), you may want [a `GinIndex`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/#django.contrib.postgres.indexes.GinIndex) as [Mahesh H Viraktamath](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4116955/mahesh-h-viraktamath) suggested in another comment.

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField   
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex

class Document(models.Model):
    content = JSONField()
    
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex("content", name="content_idx"),
        ]
```

---

Finally, for completeness, you can [select your opclass](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/gin-builtin-opclasses.html) by wrapping with [the `OpClass` expression.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/#opclass-expressions)

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField   
from django.contrib.postgres.indexes import GinIndex, OpClass

class Document(models.Model):
    content = JSONField()
    
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            GinIndex(
                OpClass(models.F("content__example_field_name"), name="jsonb_path_ops"),
                name="content__example_field_name_idx",
            ),
        ]
```

Answer (score 20):

For those that want to index a particular key, create a raw sql migration:

1. Run `./manage.py makemigrations --empty yourApp` where `yourApp` is the app of the model you want to change indexes for.
2. Edit the migration i.e.

```
operations = [
    migrations.RunSQL("CREATE INDEX idx_name ON your_table((json_field->'json_key'));")
]
```

Where `idx_name` is the name of the index, `your_table` is your table, `json_field` is your JSONField, and `json_key` in this case is the key you want to index.

Notice the `->` operator in the index creation code line, and not `->>` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57222640/django-filter-is-not-using-the-index-on-postgresql-jsonfield/57403132#57403132).

That should do it, but to verify all went well run the following sql:

```
SELECT
    indexname,
    indexdef
FROM
    pg_indexes
WHERE
    tablename = '<your-table>';
```

and see if your index is there.

Comment: I think native support was added in 3.2 as part of this PR:  https://github.com/django/django/pull/11929   But I'm not clear on how to use.  All the Django tickets requesting indexes on JSONB fields were closed based on that PR.

Answer (score 2):

There is a bit more universal and Django native way. You can use following [custom Migration Operation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/migration-operations/#writing-your-own):

```
class CreateJsonbObjectKeyIndex(Operation):

    reversible = True

    def __init__(self, model_name, field, key, index_type='btree', concurrently=False, name=None):
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.field = field
        self.key = key
        self.index_type = index_type
        self.concurrently = concurrently
        self.name = name

    def state_forwards(self, app_label, state):
        pass

    def get_names(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        table_name = from_state.apps.get_model(app_label, self.model_name)._meta.db_table
        index_name = schema_editor.quote_name(
            self.name or schema_editor._create_index_name(table_name, [f'{self.field}__{self.key}'])
        )
        return table_name, index_name

    def database_forwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        table_name, index_name = self.get_names(app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)
        schema_editor.execute(f"""
            CREATE INDEX {'CONCURRENTLY' if self.concurrently else ''} {index_name} 
            ON {table_name}
            USING {self.index_type}
            (({self.field}->'{self.key}'));
        """)

    def database_backwards(self, app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state):
        _, index_name = self.get_names(app_label, schema_editor, from_state, to_state)
        schema_editor.execute(f"DROP INDEX {index_name};")

    def describe(self):
        return f'Creates index for JSONB object field {self.field}->{self.key} of {self.model_name} model'

    @property
    def migration_name_fragment(self):
        return f'create_index_{self.model_name}_{self.field}_{self.key}'
```

Usage example:

```
from django.db import migrations

from util.migration import CreateJsonbObjectKeyIndex


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    atomic = False  # Required if concurrently=True for 0 downtime background index creation

    dependencies = [
        ('app_label', '00XX_prev_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.SeparateDatabaseAndState(
            database_operations=[
                # Operation to run custom SQL command. Check the output of `sqlmigrate` to see the auto-generated SQL
                CreateJsonbObjectKeyIndex(
                    model_name='User', field='meta', key='adid', index_type='HASH',
                    concurrently=True,
                )
            ],
        )
    ]
```

Tested with Django-2.2 and and AWS Postgres RDS, but should be compatible with other Django