# Django filter is not using the index on Postgresql JSONField

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm, jsonb, django-jsonfield

I have a Django model that contains a `PostgreSQL jsonb field`:

```
class SocialUser(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    data = JSONField(blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
```

The data field contains a `username` attribute.

I have indexed this attribute by

```
CREATE INDEX ON users_socialuser ((data->>'username'));
```

When I query it via Django ORM with the id,

```
SocialUser.objects.get(id=123)
```

and via the pgAdmin

```
SELECT * FROM users_socialuser WHERE id = 123
```

they are both fast.

But when I query with the JSONField's attribute username, pgAdmin SQL query

```
SELECT * FROM users_socialuser WHERE data->>'username' = 'abc'
```

is still equally fast, while

```
SocialUser.objects.get(data__username='abc')
```

is terribly slow.

It seems that the Django ORM is not using the index on the `username` attribute.

Why is that so? Can I explicitly force an index in Django ORM? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exploring the query generated by the Django ORM, I've noticed that the WHERE clause is like

```
data -> 'screen_name' = 'abc'
```

Notice the single arrow `->` instead of `->>`.

So, I built an index with the single arrow

```
CREATE INDEX ON users_socialuser ((data->'username'));
```

and the ORM queries are fast now too.