# Create index on nested element JSONField for Postgres in Django

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have a Django model in my python project with a meta class detailing it's indexes. I'm curious if there's a way to create the index using the nested path of the json object. In this case we know the structure of our json and I wanted to stick with a BTree or Hash index on the specific element.

If I were simply running this as raw sql, I'd expect to just do something like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foster_data(root->'level_1'->'level_2'->>'name');
```

I was hoping I could do something like this in my model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.postgres import indexes

class ParentGuardians(Facilitators): # which extends models.Model
    parent_identifier = models.IntegerField(db_column='p_id', default=None, blank=True,
                                           null=True)

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            models.UniqueConstraint(fields=['table_id', name='UniqueConstraint for Parents')
        ]
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['p_id', ]),
            indexes.BTreeIndex(fields=[models.JSONField('{"root": {"level_1": {"level_2": "name"}}}'), ]
                        ,  name="jsonb_p_id_idx"),
        ]
```

or even:

```
...
            indexes.BTreeIndex(fields=["root->'level_1'->'level_2'->>'name'", ]
...
```

But the named field `fields` only wants strings and only wants them to be the top level field defined in the model.

I'm aware of this questions: [Indexing JSONField in Django PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54824209/indexing-jsonfield-in-django-postgresql) but it seems more of a hack and wanted the result generated from the codebase and makemigrations, not to manually edit it. Is this possible more recently?

Answer (score 3):

Django 3.2 introduced native support for these indexes.

The question as asked presently doesn't seem to have the definition of the JSONField, but assuming it is something like

```py
from django.db import models

class Facilitators(models.Model):
    foster_data = models.JSONField()
```

To index a particular key, you combine an [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) with a [JSONField path lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#key-index-and-path-transforms) on [the model's Meta `indexes` option](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/options/#indexes):

```py
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import JSONField   

class Facilitators(models.Model):
    foster_data = models.JSONField()
    class Meta:
        indexes = [
            models.Index(models.F("foster_data__root__level_1__level2__name"), name="foster_data__root__level_1__level2__name_idx"),
        ]
```

[This will create a B-Tree index.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/indexes/#index-options) If you are adding these to an existing model, be sure to [`makemigrations` and `migrate`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#the-commands).

See this answer as well https://stackoverflow.com/a/74619523/

Comment: This (seems to) work in Django 4.1 without modification, but index names are restricted to max 30 chars.