# Django User Model Optimization

Tags: django, database

UserModel has many entries on it.
The 3 UserModel queries run very slow. How to make needed changes and optimizations to UserModel to make the 3 queries run faster?

```
class UserModel(models.Model):
  username = CharField(max_length=255)
  role = JSONField() # format of ['admin', 'operator']

UserModel.objects.filter(username='john').first()
UserModel.objects.filter(username__contains='doe').first()  
UserModel.objects.filter(role__contains='operator').first()
```

Comment: If there is an option you should change JSONField to separate table/M2M field. Storing JSON in relational database most of the times have no sense and should be avoided due to performance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have many records in the table, you have to use indexes. Let's go by the queries.

1. `UserModel.objects.filter(username='john')` just filters records for equality, so a [BTree index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/#btreeindex) will simply handle this.
2. `UserModel.objects.filter(username__contains='doe')` is translated to `ILIKE '%doe%'`, so we need something like [trigram index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html). To use that add `django.contrib.postgres` in your `INSTALLED_APPS` and activate the `pg_trgm` extension on PostgreSQL. You can install the extension using the [TrigramExtension](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#django.contrib.postgres.operations.TrigramExtension) migration operation.
3. `UserModel.objects.filter(role__contains='operator')` filters only records which contain given key. This query can be optimized with [Gin index](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/indexes/#django.contrib.postgres.indexes.GinIndex). See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74619523/12914274) for implementation details.